# do some versions of dd not understand multiplicative suffixes?

Tags: linux, dd, suffix

I was wondering if there are certain versions of dd that don't understand multiplicative suffixes. From the dd man page it says:

```
bs=BYTES
    read and write BYTES bytes at a time (also see ibs=,obs=) 
BLOCKS and BYTES may be followed by the following multiplicative suffixes: c =1, w =2, b =512, kB =1000, K =1024, MB =1000*1000, M =1024*1024, xM =M GB =1000*1000*1000, G =1024*1024*1024, and so on for T, P, E, Z, Y.
```

but when I ran dd with a G suffix on the bs parameter I got an error about the number not being understood:

```
bash $ dd if=/dev/urandom of=largeMovie.avi count=1024 bs=75G
dd: invalid number `75G'
```

The version of dd is as follows:

```
bash $ dd --version
dd (coreutils) 5.97
```

A

Comment: better to be moved to http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: it would get wider coverage here and therefore have more of a chance in getting answered

Comment: @amadain: The point is not "coverage", it is topicality.  Your question is off-topic according to the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on 32 bit and 75G is bigger than size_t.
Even on 64 bit you'll need at least that amount of mem available as dd will allocate a buffer of the size specified by bs.

Answer (score 1):

`G` is not a standard suffix. The behavior is therefore undefined.

The only standard suffixes are `k` (1024) and `b` (512). If you want anything else, you can use `x` between several numbers with suffixes to multiply:

```
dd bs=1024 count=75x1024x1024x1024
```

(Your example tries to allocate 75GiB of RAM which is rarely ok, so I switched the `bs` and `count`)

Here's what [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html) says:

> For the bs=, cbs=, ibs=, and obs= operands, the application shall supply an expression specifying a size in bytes. The expression, expr, can be:
>
> A positive decimal number
>
> A positive decimal number followed by k, specifying multiplication by 1024
>
> A positive decimal number followed by b, specifying multiplication by 512
>
> Two or more positive decimal numbers (with or without k or b) separated by x, specifying the product of the indicated values